# How do I go from a custom cell to an imageView?

Tags: swift, xcode, imageview, tableview

I already have an array of data for my custom table view cells.This includes just an imageView and label at present.

I'm wanting to seque to a separate view controller with imageView to show the small thumbnail image as a large version. But, of course, using my array of data so that the correct image loads in the host imageView.

Basically, I would like to create a host imageView that will load up my array of data as I select it from the list.

My current array is as below:

```
import UIKit

class PictureViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var pictures: [picture] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pictures = createArray()

        tableView.rowHeight = 120


        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    func createArray() -> [picture] {

        var tempPictures: [picture] = []

        let picture1 = picture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Arteries Hand"), title: "Arteries Hand")
        let picture2 = picture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Arteries Upper Arm"), title: "Arteries Upper Arm")
        let picture3 = picture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Arteries Shoulder"), title: "Arteries Shoulder")
        let picture4 = picture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Arteries Upper Limb"), title: "Arteries Upper Limb")

    tempPictures.append(picture1)
    tempPictures.append(picture2)
    tempPictures.append(picture3)
    tempPictures.append(picture4)

        return tempPictures
    }
}


extension PictureViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let picture = pictures[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pictureCell") as! pictureCell

     cell.setPicture(picture: picture)

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

    }
}
```

PictureCell:

```
import UIKit

class pictureCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var pictureImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pictureTitleLabel: UILabel!

    func setPicture(picture: picture) {
        pictureImageView.image = picture.image
        pictureTitleLabel.text = picture.title
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have written in your picture cell class?

Comment: your ques not clear.

Comment: Your implementation of `didSelectRowAt` is unnecessary as it stands, because all you do is call `performSegue` and you can configure that directly in the storyboard instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

The above method triggers following class method, and you can use it to transfer data :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let segueId = segue.identifier else { return }

    switch segueId {
    case "segue":

        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! YournextVC
        destVC.pictures = self.pictures // This is how you transfer info to the next View Controller 

    default:
        break
    }
}
```